# Javascript работа с файлами

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Есть страница (`html`, `javascript`, `css`), нет сервера.

Все закидывается на клиент каждый и работает локально, и просто через `ajax` тянет необходимые данные с веб-сервисов.

Нужно чтоб при редизаине и.т.п случаях `javascript` скачивал файлы с сервера и заменял в клиенте все (`html`, `javascript`, `css`) файлы. Как я зная это не возможно поскольку `javascript` не умеет работать с файлами (по крайней мере браузерный `javascript`).

Может я ошибаюсь? есть у кого мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: это велосипед о квадратных колесах. используйте веб сервер.

Comment: Запросто можно качать обновления и сохранять через File System API в браузере. Можно и не сохранять, а каждый раз на старте выкачивать новые.

Comment: А можно примерчик. если не затруднит?

Comment: Где в File System API есть доступ к диску на запись?

Comment: А в чем проблема иметь ссылку на стили и скрипты просто по ссылки на другой домен? `<script src="http://vasya.pypkin/scripts.js"></script>` И не нужно городить ваши костыли непонятные

Comment: Можно написать расширение для браузера.

Comment: @AlexeyTen вот здесь можно почитать https://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а это где-нибудь работает? _Work on this document has been discontinued and it should not be referenced or used as a basis for implementation._

Comment: _скачивал файлы с сервера_ — это подразумевает наличие сервера. Непонятно о чём тогда вопрос…

Comment: @AlexeyTen пользуюсь в хроме для хранения шрифтов, с другими браузерами да, проблема (там можно localStorage/sessionStorage, но не так удобно из-за ограничений на размер, приходится дробить на куски/склеивать).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian ну вот только хром и песочница не похоже на то, что нужно автору. Хотя песочницу можно пережить. Впрочем желание автора всё равно какое-то противоречивое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В HTML5 есть возможность работать с файловой системой, но с некоторыми ограничениями. Можете поискать информацию о File System API и File API. Хорошо все разжевано в [этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112286/)